# Is my python trading bot calculating MACD wrongly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, algorithmic-trading, trading

My python trading bot calculates MACD to be very high at the beginning and then begins a gradual descent no matter what stock or how the stock is actually moving.

[Here is the matplotlib chart of the MACD and Signal Line (All stocks/crytocurrency's plots look very similar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZlIv.png)

I tried tweaking the span values but to no avail. This occurs to any stock / crypto currency I use it with. This code is based on Computer Science's MACD trading tutorial but adapted to trade in real time rather than generate a chart for past data and log and other stuff. (Also I am new to coding so please try to explain what is going on in simple terms) This is the code:

```
    def algorithm(self, df):
    '''
    Generates MACD

    '''

    # Set the date(first column) to be the index of the dataframe
    df = df.set_index(df[self.time_stamp_index])
    # print(df.head())

    # Visually show the stock price
    if self.do_plotting == True:
        # print('Plotting Data')
        plt1 = px.line(df, x=self.time_stamp_index,
                       y=self.close_price_index)

    # Calculate the MACD and signal line indicators

    # Calculate the Short term EWM(for 10 minutes)
    ShortEMA = df[self.close_price_index].ewm(
        span=self.short_span, adjust=False).mean()

    # Calculate the long term exponential moving avg (1 hour)
    LongEMA = df[self.close_price_index].ewm(
        span=self.long_span, adjust=False).mean()

    # Calculate the MACD line
    MACD = ShortEMA - LongEMA

    # Calculate signal line
    signal = MACD.ewm(span=self.signal_span, adjust=False).mean()

    # Add signal line and MACD line to dataframe
    df['MACD'] = MACD
    df['Signal Line'] = signal

    # Plot the chart with the lines
    if self.do_plotting == True:
        plt2 = px.line(df, x=self.time_stamp_index, y=[
            'MACD', 'Signal Line', self.close_price_index],
            title=f'{self.symbol} STOCK DATA')
        plt2.show()

    # DEBUG
    if df['MACD'][len(df) - 1] > df['Signal Line'][len(df) - 1]:
        print('[DEBUG]: BUY SIGNAL')

    elif df['MACD'][len(df) - 1] < df['Signal Line'][len(df) - 1]:
        print('[DEBUG]: SELL SIGNAL')

    # send vals to self. so that it can be accessed from the log function.
    self.macd = df['MACD'][len(df) - 1]
    self.signal_line = df['Signal Line'][len(df) - 1]

    Buy = []
    Sell = []

    current_hold_flag = self.symbol in current_stocks

    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df['MACD'][i] > df['Signal Line'][i]:
            Sell.append(None)
            if current_hold_flag == False:
                Buy.append(df[self.close_price_index][i])
                self.flag = 1
            else:
                Buy.append(None)
        elif df['MACD'][i] < df['Signal Line'][i]:
            Buy.append(None)
            if current_hold_flag == True:
                Sell.append(df[self.close_price_index][i])
                self.flag = 0
            else:
                Sell.append(None)
        else:
            Buy.append(None)
            Sell.append(None)

    buy_sell = (Buy, Sell)

    df['Buy_Signal_Price'] = buy_sell[0]
    df['Sell Signal_Price'] = buy_sell[1] 

    if Buy[-1] != None:                             # If last trade was a buy
        self.buy_or_sell = 'buy'
        self.buy(Buy[-1])
    elif Sell[-1] != None:                          # If last trade was a sell
        self.buy_or_sell = 'sell'
        self.sell(Sell[-1])
    elif Buy[-1] == None and Sell[-1] == None:      # If no trade happened
        self.buy_or_sell = 'no trade' 
        print(f'{self.log_time}Did not trade')
        if len(current_stocks) > 0:
            print(
                f'{self.log_time}Currently holding: {",".join(current_stocks)}')
        else:

            print(f'{self.log_time}Not holding any stocks currently')
    else:
        print('ERROR')
        r = input()
        exit()
```

Comment: Happy to provide any other necessary data

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I would look at your calculations and compare to a respected stock charting site and see if your calcs match with the site for the same short long and signal averages. That said these are exponential weighted averages and when the calculations start there's no history so it takes some time for the weightings to kick in. You may want to exclude a certain number of data points at the beginning of your timeseries in your analysis after calculating macd and signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to earn money from trading crypto, you can be interested in using information about new currency listings ang=nd adding new pairs at the biggest exchanges, if used correctly, you can earn about 20% per day. To get information about new listings at crypto exchanges, you can be interested in using this API:

https://rapidapi.com/Diver44/api/new-cryptocurrencies-listings/

It includes an endpoint with New Listings, New Pairs from the biggest exchanges, and a very useful endpoint with information about exchanges where you can buy specific coins and prices for this coin at that exchange. It's a bit paid, but it's worth it!